# Problem when using hyperref together with cleveref

Tags: hyperref, errors, cross-referencing, cleveref

As it says in the `cleveref` documentation `hyperref` must be loaded before cleveref. But at me I have to load at least one package between them and I would really like to know why.

The not working minimal example is

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{Def}{Definition}
\newtheorem{Lemma}[Def]{Lemma}
\begin{document}
a
\begin{Lemma}
\label{Lem:fastdis}
\[ a+b=c? \]
\end{Lemma}
\end{document}
```

This just gives an error and doesn't compile, but switching amsthm and hyperref like this

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{Def}{Definition}
\newtheorem{Lemma}[Def]{Lemma}
\begin{document}
a
\begin{Lemma}
\label{Lem:fastdis}
\[ a+b=c? \]
\end{Lemma}
\end{document}
```

it compiles without even a warning. Why do i need to load a package between them?

Comment: "Just gives an error"? What error? The first MWE works just fine for me. Maybe you’re using outdated version of the packages.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel the only thing that looks like an error is "
\AtBegShi@Output ...ipout \box \AtBeginShipoutBox 
                                                  \fi \fi 
l.14 \end{document}
                   ]
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AfterLastShipout' on input line 14." The last time I updated is about 2 weeks ago I just gonna check for updates

Comment: I guess you just answered yourself: putting `amsthm` between `hyperref` and `cleveref` seems to solve the issue.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Updated and here with MiKTeX 2.9 and WinEdt 7.1 it doesn't compile anything.